# The schema for MySQL lookup table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, lookup

Not sure exactly how I should be setting this up as far as databases go.

In words what I need to do is query one funding source from either my `credit cards` table or my `bank account` table.  There can only be one funding source between the two tables. So I am thinking do I need a lookup table?

Here is what I am thinking for tables:

table 1

```
id    user_id    credit_card_num   
1     22         2222222222222222
2     55         3333333333333333
```

table 2

```
id    user_id    bank_account_num
1     22         2323232323232323
2     55         2323232234323423
```

table 3

```
id    user_id    funding_source_id    type
1     22         1                    1 (or CreditCard table)
2     55         2                    2 (or BankAccount table)
```

So again a user can only have one funding source, which could either live in the `credit card` table or bank `account table`. Is this needed?

And for the Laravel crew. If this is correct is there an Eloquent relationship that would work for this? From what I am seeing in the Documentation I don't think so.

Please give me your advise.

Citti

Comment: What do you mean by "set this up"?

Comment: does this logic look right? as far as a lookup table goes? Lookup tables are new to me.

Comment: and then thinking of the Laravel eloquent query for this. Would there be a relationship that would cover this...

Comment: Other than the fact that one stores a credit card number and the other stores a bank account number, is there any difference between these tables? Also, if this is for anything other than the storage of your own personal card and account details, forget it.

Comment: yea a bank account has the main account number and routing number. where the CC has the secret and other stuff that differs. so the tables differ. and dont want to have null's in them. ..

Comment: this is to store others CC info... with out getting into all the details I am storing the actual numbers on another server. encrypted etc etc. but this would be for quick look ups.